# Optimising speed with the map() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

So I currently have a project where I have to simulate a high resolution image through a satellite image. I'm doing this with Python, and I have a program that works - BUT, it takes 3 minutes to simulate over the typical image size (1200 by 1500 pixels). I've been testing the code for time and found this is the most time consuming part of the script, which takes 3 minutes (the rest of the code makes up about 10 more seconds).

Here is that portion of code:

```
def weight_values(Pix_center,row_0,row_1,col_0,col_1,t_row_0,t_row_1,t_col_0,t_col_1):
    foot_in_truth = foots[Pix_center,row_0:row_1,col_0:col_1]
    truth_in_foot = truth[t_row_0:t_row_1, t_col_0:t_col_1]
    weighted_vals = (foot_in_truth*truth_in_foot).sum()/foot_in_truth.sum()
    return weighted_vals

no_mask = np.where(np.ma.getmaskarray(Pix_centers) == False)
weighted_mean = np.array(map(weight_values, (Pix_centers[no_mask]),(row0[no_mask]),(row1[no_mask]),(col0[no_mask]),(col1[no_mask]),(truth_row0[no_mask]),(truth_row1[no_mask]),(truth_col0[no_mask]),(truth_col1[no_mask])))
```

In the above, my **weight_values** function takes lots of values. And when they are called using **map**, the iterables given are all 1 dimensional objects of the same size.

Here is a brief description of the arrays involved:

- foots: a 3D array with dimensions pixel number, along track and across track (the last two are non-localized, i.e. they are centered at 0). This represents the footprint of the satellite at each pixel. The footprint is essentially how much area is actually inside each pixel - I'm using an instrument which has a large swath which is why this is important.
- truth: this is the thing I'm simulating. It's got the same resolution as foots, but covers a specific area over the along-track and across-track coordinates

the 1D arrays called in the map function as iterables have masked values, which is why 'no_mask' is used. These arrays have a maximum value of 1800000 (the number of image pixels) but my code allows me to select smaller segments for testing.

This approach works! But I was wondering if there is any way to speed it up. I've tried so far with a map/lambda setup (which was almost two times slower), a list comprehension and a for loop. So far, this approach is the fastest across my entire 1.8 million pixel sample. Please let me know if you have any ideas as to how to speed it up. I would post the whole code here but a lot of it is irrelevant, plus it uses files on my local machine which I'm not sure I have authorization to share.

Also let me know if anything here isn't clear or you don't understand the question, and I'll try my best to make it more readable.

Comment: Serious question, are you able / have you tried upgrading to Python 3.x?

Comment: No, I've stuck with 2.7 for now because it seems there's more help available for that, and when I started I wasn't as comfortable with python. Do you think this will help some of the speed issues I'm seeing?

Answer (score 3):

I took a quick look of your `weight_value` function, which does an averaging for each pixel, and each pixel has many neighbors. Therefore, each neighbor pixel is read many times. This runs in O(n^3) time. A common, faster, technique is a Cumulative sum. You can start from [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html), although it is in Matlab. The idea is the same in python. The goal is that you only need to compute each pixel value once.
The python version is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. For an answer such as this, you could include a minimal explanation of the cumulative sum algorithm based on the links.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. essentially my 'foot_in_truth' is finding the elements of my 'foot' array that would fall into the bounds of my 'truth' array, and vice versa for 'truth_in_foots'. My Pix_centers array is what is being called on from 'foot' to create the 'foot_in_truth' array, but I don't see a way I can prevent this being sometimes created for duplicate pixel numbers. This is because the arrays 'row1,row0,col1,col0' are all individual to their specific elements, and this defines what portion of the footprint I slice. But it's definitely something for me to think about!